# Django No Pet matches the given query

Tags: django

I have a simple pet app.

The app display all the pet stores and when you click on the pet store . You will get to see all the pet names, picture .

The problem is after I created the first pet and other pets . The template doesn't update the new pets . So , it only display the first pet.

So when I delete the first pet . It displays Page not found (404) even though . I added new pets to the store.

I tried to use a for loop inside the template but it display an error that I can't iterate over it and  A friend told me not to use for loop when you are rendering only single data.

How Can I display more pets at a store?

I think the problem is at my animal.html also my views.py

my animal.html

```
 {% if pet %}
 <li>Pet = {{ pet.animal }}</li>
 <li>description = {{pet.description}} </li>

 <img src="{{ pet.image.url }}">
 {% endif %}
```

my store.html

```
 Sydney's Pet Store
 {% if store %}
 <ul>
    {% for a in store %}
    <li><a href ="{% url world:brazil a.id %}">{{ a.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}

 </ul>
 {% endif %}
```

My views.py

```
 from pet.models import Store , Pet
 from django.shortcuts import render_to_response ,get_object_or_404

 def index(request):
    store = Store.objects.all()
    return render_to_response ('store.html',{'store':store})

 def brazil(request , animal_id):
    pet = get_object_or_404(Pet, pk=animal_id)
    return render_to_response ('animal.html',{'pet':pet})
```

My models.py

```
 from django.db import models

 class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    number = models.BigIntegerField()
    address =models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

 class Pet(models.Model):
    animal = models.CharField(max_length =20)
    description = models.TextField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Store)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.animal
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to show more than 1 data, you must use filter not get_object_or_404. 
You will use get_object_or_404 if you want to show only 1 data.

```
def brazil(request , owner_id):
    pets = Pet.objects.filter(owner_id=owner_id)
    return render_to_response ('animal.html',{'pets':pets})


{% if pets %}
 <ul>
    {% for pet in pets %}
    <li>
        Pet = {{ pet.animal }}<br/>
        description = {{pet.description}}<br/> 
        <img src="{{ pet.image.url }}">
    </li>
    {% endfor %}

 </ul>
 {% endif %}
```

Comment: Would you use a ManyToManyField or a ForeignKey in my situation?

Comment: The foreignkey of the owner of store

Comment: as you click the store you want to show the list of pets in that store, right?

Answer (score 1):

Create a queryset in your view (something like) -

```
 def brazil(request , animal_id):
    pets = Pet.objects.all()
    return render_to_response ('animal.html',{'pets':pets})
```

Then iterate it in your template -

```
{% for pet in pets %}
 <li>Pet = {{ pet.animal }}</li>
 <li>description = {{pet.description}} </li>
 <img src="{{ pet.image.url }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Have a look at the [queryset docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/) to get more idea of how to pass the objects you want to your templates